# не работает отправка электронной почты

Tags: c#, .net, email

Пытаюсь отправить email сам себе - не отправляется. Всё перепроверил, не вижу где ошибку - всё вроде стандартно и тривиально. Делал на примере Metanit https://metanit.com/sharp/net/8.1.php

Пробовал с нескольких почт - всё отражено в коде

В случае с mail.ru ошибка SmtpException has occured: The operation has timed out.

В случае с yandex.ru ошибка SmtpException has occured: Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной почты

Так же пробовал незащищённое соединение (порты 20, 2025, enableSSL = false)

Где ошибка?

```
public void SendEmailMetanit()
    {
        try
        {
            var mail = "aleynikov.oleg@yandex.ru";
            var pass = "xxx";
            var smtpServer = "smtp.yandex.ru";
            var port = 465;
            var enableSSL = true;

            //var mail = "city.move@mail.ru";
            //var pass = "xxx";
            //var smtpServer = "smtp.mail.ru";
            //var port = 465;
            //var enableSSL = true;

            //var mail = "aleynikov.oleg@gmail.com";
            //var pass = "xxx";
            //var smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
            //var port = 465;
            //var enableSSL = true;

            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(mail, port);

            // отправитель - устанавливаем адрес и отображаемое в письме имя
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(mail, "Tom");
            // кому отправляем
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(mail);
            // создаем объект сообщения
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
            // тема письма
            m.Subject = "Тест";
            // текст письма
            m.Body = "<h2>Письмо-тест работы smtp-клиента</h2>";
            // письмо представляет код html
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            // адрес smtp-сервера и порт, с которого будем отправлять письмо
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, port);
            // логин и пароль
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail, pass);
            //mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
            smtp.Send(m);
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException
              ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [SmtpPort = 587](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850434/312041) ?

Comment: для какой почты?

Comment: нажмите на ссылку и узнаете.

Comment: Ошибка "Неправильная последовательность команд. Отклик сервера: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first."}

Comment: `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; smtp.Credentials = ...;` Порядок вызова важен

Comment: возникает та же ошибка